# Onto and one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional inner product space $V$. If $T$ has an eigenvector, then so does $T^*$.

**Proof.** Suppose that $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then for any $x \in V$,
$$
0 = \langle0,x\rangle = \langle(T-\lambda I)v,x\rangle
= \langle v, (T-\lambda I)^*x\rangle = \langle v,(T^*-\bar{\lambda} I)x\rangle
$$
This means that $(T^*-\bar{\lambda} I)$ is not onto. WHY?
(Of course the proof is not completed in here)

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your proof. Specifically, the term after the third equal to sign is wrong. You do not need that, the term after the second equal to sign is equal to the last term by the definition of adjoint.

Comment: Actually it's not mine. It's from the friedberg's book.

Comment: This is correct. If it was onto, you would get $(v,y)=0$ for every $y\in V$, whence $v=0$.

Comment: If $T^* - \lambda I$ were onto, then wouldnt you be able to find an $x$ such that $(T^* - \lambda I)x = v$? Then what can you say about $v$?

Comment: Oops, its correct. I did not see the star at the top!

Comment: @julien Thanks!

Comment: @julien Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $T^*-\overline{\lambda}I$ is onto and take $v$ such that $(T-\lambda I)v=0$.

By surjectivity, there exists $x\in V$ such that $(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)x=v$. For this specific $x$, we get
$$
0=(v,(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)x)=(v,v)=\|v\|^2\quad \Rightarrow \quad v=0.
$$
Therefore $T^*-\overline{\lambda}I$ surjective implies $T-\lambda I$ injective.

By rank-nullity and symmetry, it follows that $T-\lambda I$ is not injective if and only if $T^*-\overline{\lambda}I$ is not injective. That is $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue for $T$ if and only if $\overline{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue for $T^*$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know why $T^{*}$ is not onto if $T$ is not onto, just observe that the matrix of $T^{*}$ is just the conjugate transpose of the matrix of $T$ and we know that a matrix and its conjugate transpose have the same rank (which is equal to the dimension of the range space).